# For loop to generate urls with attribute (n - 1) * 16

Tags: r, for-loop

I need to go through all the values in my column `f_urls$paginas`, take that integer (`n`) and generate a for loop of the same lenght as this number to generate `n` new urls.

The only difference is that each url has an attribute starting at `0` and summing up until `(n - 1) * 16`

For example:

`http://www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat2090462/Marcas-Accesorios?No=0&Nrpp=16`

The next one would be:

`http://www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat2090462/Marcas-Accesorios?No=16&Nrpp=16`

and so on...until `(n - 1) * 16` is in the last url attribute:

`http://www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat2090462/Marcas-Accesorios?No=` + `(n - 1) * 16` + `&Nrpp=16`

I've made a for loop, but it isn't giving me the expected results.

```
setwd("C:\\extraer-datos")



f_urls <- read.csv("falabella-urls-test.csv", sep = ";")




falabella_urls <- c()


#####

parte_a = "?No="
parte_b = "&Nrpp=16"

###

#num_page = 0

###


for (i in seq_along(f_urls$categoria)) {


  for (j in seq_along(1:f_urls$paginas[i])) {

        num_page = j
        num_page = (num_page - 1) * 16

        falabella_urls <- c(falabella_urls, paste0(f_urls$url[f_urls$paginas[i]], parte_a, num_page, parte_b))

  }
}
```

It is generating values urls like:

```
NA?No=0&Nrpp=16
NA?No=16&Nrpp=16
NA?No=32&Nrpp=16
NA?No=48&Nrpp=16
```

Others are good but not complete:

```
www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat4350568/Joyas?No=0&Nrpp=16
www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat4350568/Joyas?No=16&Nrpp=16
www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat4350568/Joyas?No=32&Nrpp=16
www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat4350568/Joyas?No=48&Nrpp=16
```

The last url for joyas should end in `?No=112&Nrpp=16` (You can see each correct ending in the column `distribucion` of the df.

#### ======  DATA =======

```
f_urls <- structure(list(categoria = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("Accesorios", 
"Hombre", "Mujer", "Varios"), class = "factor"), url = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat4350568/Joyas", 
"www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat510499/Lentes-de-Sol", 
"www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat7230497/Accesorios-Hombre", 
"www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat7230498/Accesorios-Mujer", 
"www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat7230499/Carteras-y-Bolsos"
), class = "factor"), paginas = c(37L, 4L, 23L, 8L, 2L), distribucion = structure(c(5L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("?No=112&Nrpp=16", "?No=16&Nrpp=16", 
"?No=352&Nrpp=16", "?No=48&Nrpp=16", "?No=576&Nrpp=16"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("categoria", 
"url", "paginas", "distribucion"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: What do you want the result to look like? And do you want that in a vector, data.frame, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

`falabella_urls <- c(falabella_urls, paste0(f_urls$url[f_urls$paginas[i]], parte_a, num_page, parte_b))`

you take the page number, then pick the row in `f_urls` that corresponds to that number. Most page numbers are far higher than the number of rows, so you get NA.

Try

`falabella_urls <- c(falabella_urls, paste0(f_urls$url[i], parte_a, num_page, parte_b))`

or (even better) Ryan's solution

Answer (score 1):

This fixes the problem and also runs a lot faster:

```
newUrls<-unlist(sapply(df$paginas,
                       function(n)paste0("?No=",(seq_along(1:n)-1)*16,"&Nrpp=16")))

newUrls<-paste0(rep(df$url,df$paginas), newUrls)
```

"Joyas" subset of output (i.e. newUrls[65:72]):

```
[1] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat4350568/Joyas?No=0&Nrpp=16"  
[2] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat4350568/Joyas?No=16&Nrpp=16" 
[3] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat4350568/Joyas?No=32&Nrpp=16" 
[4] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat4350568/Joyas?No=48&Nrpp=16" 
[5] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat4350568/Joyas?No=64&Nrpp=16" 
[6] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat4350568/Joyas?No=80&Nrpp=16" 
[7] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat4350568/Joyas?No=96&Nrpp=16" 
[8] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat4350568/Joyas?No=112&Nrpp=16"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
ans <- df %>%
         nest(url, paginas) %>%
         mutate(data = map(data, ~paste0(.x$url, "?No=", cumsum(c(0, rep(16, .x$paginas))), "&Nrpp=16"))) %>%
         unnest(data) %>%
         rename(newurls = data)

 ans$newurls

 [1] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat7230497/Accesorios-Hombre?No=0&Nrpp=16"  
 [2] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat7230497/Accesorios-Hombre?No=16&Nrpp=16" 
 [3] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat7230497/Accesorios-Hombre?No=32&Nrpp=16" 
 [4] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat7230497/Accesorios-Hombre?No=48&Nrpp=16" 
 [5] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat7230497/Accesorios-Hombre?No=64&Nrpp=16" 
 [6] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat7230497/Accesorios-Hombre?No=80&Nrpp=16" 
 [7] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat7230497/Accesorios-Hombre?No=96&Nrpp=16" 
 [8] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat7230497/Accesorios-Hombre?No=112&Nrpp=16"
  # etc
```

You might need to subtract 1 from paginas as `.x$paginas-1` to get the right output

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
  Map(function(x,n)paste0(x,"?No=",0:(n-1)*16,"&Nrpp=16"),f_urls$url,f_urls$paginas)
```

> [[4]]
>   [1] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat4350568/Joyas?No=0&Nrpp=16"
>   [2] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat4350568/Joyas?No=16&Nrpp=16" 
>   [3] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat4350568/Joyas?No=32&Nrpp=16" 
>   [4] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat4350568/Joyas?No=48&Nrpp=16" 
>   [5] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat4350568/Joyas?No=64&Nrpp=16" 
>   [6] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat4350568/Joyas?No=80&Nrpp=16" 
>   [7] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat4350568/Joyas?No=96&Nrpp=16" 
>   [8] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat4350568/Joyas?No=112&Nrpp=16"
>
> [[5]]
>   [1] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat510499/Lentes-de-Sol?No=0&Nrpp=16" 
>   [2] "www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat510499/Lentes-de-Sol?No=16&Nrpp=16"

etc etc...